# How to send application form with data which is taken from backend to mail using php mail function

Tags: php, html

my form structure go to the mail but my values are blank.My database values does not get replaced in quotes.How to write it inside qupte when i am using  tag

```
   <?php
   $eid = $_SESSION['id1'];
    $select= "SELECT email from emp_details where id = '".$eid."' ";
    $result= mysql_query($select);

    $rows= mysql_fetch_array($result);

     $to= $rows['email'];
    /
    //$a=5;
     $subject = "Application form print";
     $message = "Warehousing Corporation Employees Welfare Fund Apllication form are as given below.<br>";
     $message .= "<br>"; 
     $message .= '<html><body>';

     $message .= "<div  style= 'border-style: solid; border-width: medium;margin: auto;padding: 10px;width: 1024px;'>
<h2 style='text-align:center;'> Warehousing Corporation Employees Welfare Fund  </h2>
<h2 style='text-align:center;'> Application form  </h2>
<br>Application Id :<b><?php echo $_SESSION["id1"]; ?></b>";
     $message .= "</body></html>";
     $message .= "<br>Regards,<br>";
     $message .= "Team| Welfare Fund.<br>";
     $message .= "Email- welfarefund.mswc@gmail.com | Web- www.welfarefundmswc.com<<br>";
     $message .= "Contact – 8408882561<br>";                                               
     $headers = "From: welfarefund.mswc@gmail.com" . "\r\n";
     $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$to = $rows[0]['email'];` because you are using `mysql_fetch_array`

and change this because you are using the php session

```
$message .= "<div  style= 'border-style: solid; border-width: medium;margin: auto;padding: 10px;width: 1024px;'>
<h2 style='text-align:center;'> Warehousing Corporation Employees Welfare Fund  </h2>
<h2 style='text-align:center;'> Application form  </h2>
<br>Application Id :<b>". $_SESSION['id1']."</b>";
```